# Conditionally format a list of two-word items with A B treated the same as B A

Tags: function, google-sheets, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

What I have in Column A is a list of two-word items that need checking against each other to see if there are any duplicates. I have a formula in place:

```
=countif(A:A,A1)>1
```

with the range entered as `A1:A1000`, that will highlight duplicates if they are entered in the same order. For example, `Dog Cat` would highlight `Dog Cat`. But I also want it highlight `Dog Cat` if I enter `Cat Dog`.

What formula would I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try a *Custom formula is* of:

```
=and(countif(A$1:A1,A1)>1,or(countif(A:A,A1)>1,countif(A:A,"="&left(A1,find(" ",A1)-1)&mid(A1,find(" ",A1),len(A1)-find(" ",A1)+1))>1))
```

Applied to ColumnA with the text copied from ColumnB and Formatting style of yellow fill the results are:

[image: SO27289468 example]

That is, the first instance from the top of *both* orders of a pair of words is not formatted.

Comment: Thanks, but that highlights everything not just duplicated items. How can I stop that?
If it helps the list will be something like this:
**Cat Dog,**
Cat Bird,
**Dog Cat,**
Dog Bird,
**Cat Dog,**
Bird Gerbil,